# Color Sampler QGIS 2.6

Tags: qgis

I can't find the color sampler (to select a color from anywhere on the desktop and have this copied into QGIS) in QGIS 2.6. I attach a screenshot on where QGIS says it is meant to be.

[image]

Comment: I think one step back there is a drop-down next to the basic fill colour that says "pick colour"...?

Answer (score 4):

It's not available on OSX, due to platform limitations.

Answer (score 1):

It's here in 2.8, probably the same in 2.10

[image]